# What should be the json format for this json response?

Tags: java

Below is the json response retrieved from the api

```
[
  {"employee":{"id":1,"name":"somu","employee_company":{"id":100,"name":"comp1"}}},
  {"employee":    {"id":2,"name":"raju","employee_company":{"id":101,"name":"comp2"}}},
  {"employee":{"id":3,"name":"nagu","employee_company":{"id":105,"name":"comp5"}}}
]
```

Not sure how to define the java equivalent structure to consume the above json response

```
a. List<EmployeeDTO> where EmployeeDTO has Employee object and EmployeeCompany Object (OR)
b. List<Map<String, EmployeeDTO>> where EmployeeDTO has id, name attribute and EmployeeCompany Object

restTemplate.exchange
        (RequestEntity.get(new URI(url)).headers(headers).build(), EmployeeDTO.class);

(or)

`  restTemplate.exchange(
     BASE_URL,
     HttpMethod.GET,
     null,
     new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<EmployeeDTO>>() {}
 );`
```

1. EmployeeDTO -> Employee + EmployeeCompany
2. Employee + EmployeeCompany (no employee DTO)

Can you please help me with the DTO structure align with the above json and also the rest API call with
response class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For fast convert u can use
   https://json2csharp.com/code-converters/json-to-pojo

it offers

```
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; // version 2.11.1
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty; // version 2.11.1
/* ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Root[] root = om.readValue(myJsonString, Root[].class); */
public class Employee{
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public EmployeeCompany employee_company;
}

public class EmployeeCompany{
    public int id;
    public String name;
}

public class Root{
    public Employee employee;
}
```

2. Call remote url and get a list

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-list

```
EmployeeList response = restTemplate.getForObject(
  "http://localhost:8080/employees",
  EmployeeList.class);
List<Employee> employees = response.getEmployees();
```

Comment: Tried

https://json2csharp.com/code-converters/json-to-pojo
https://jsonformatter.org/json-to-java
https://codebeautify.org/json-to-java-converter
https://jsonlint.com/